# Как правильно вывести LIST аккаунтов с увеличением номера на 1?

Tags: java

У меня есть класс `Account` , в котором присутствует `toString` :

```
 @Override
public String toString() {
    return "Account {" +
            "client=" + client.getName() + " " +  client.getSurname() +
            ", currency='" + currency + '\'' +
            ", money=" + money +
            '}';
}
```

Позже, в классе `Main` после работы с аккаунтами, мне нужно вывести список аккаунтов клиента ( делаю это таким образом :

```
for (Account account : accountList) {

            System.out.println(account);
        }
```

Внимание ВОПРОС : Как выводить список аккаунтов, чтобы при выводе номер аккаунта увеличивался на 1?

Предположим, у клиента 3 аккаунта, и чтобы выводило не просто

```
Account{ bla-bla-bla } 
Account{ bla-bla-bla } 
Account{ bla-bla-bla }
```

, а данным образом :

```
Account №1 { bla } 
Account №2 { bla } 
Account №3 { bla-bla }
```

Comment: Могу предложить использовать обычный `for` c выводом переменной-счетчика, вот так: `S.o.p("Account №"+i+" - " + Account.toString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант может быть и кривоватый, но почему бы и нет:

```
class Account {
    .
    .
    .
    private static int accNo;
    private static boolean isDisplayNumber;

    public static void setDisplayModeWithNumber(boolean isDisplayNumber) {
        Account.isDisplayNumber = isDisplayNumber;
        accNo = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account" + (isDisplayNumber ? " №" + accNo++ : "") + " {" +
                "client=" + client.getName() + " " + client.getSurname() +
                ", currency='" + currency + '\'' +
                ", money=" + money +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Вывод без номеров:

```
Account.setDisplayModeWithNumber(false);
for (Account account: list)
    System.out.println(account);
```

Вывод с номерами:

```
Account.setDisplayModeWithNumber(true);
for (Account account: list)
    System.out.println(account);
```

но придётся перед вызовом каждой группы toString() определяться с режимом вывода.

Answer (score 1):

Пример из книги Философия Java.

```
package net.mindview.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Account {
    private static long counter = 1;
    private final long id = counter++;

    public Account() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account{" +
                "id=" + id +
                '}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new Account(),
                new Account(),
                new Account(),
                new Account()
        ));

        for (Account account : accountList) {
            System.out.println(account);
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Account{id=1}
Account{id=2}
Account{id=3}
Account{id=4}
```